# How to delete job artifacts after merge request is accepted in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using the gitlab runner and a .gitlab-ci.yml file. I have a job that is only executed on merge requests. Is there a possibility to delete the exposed job artifacts after the merge request is deleted? I have no access to the gitlab API, so doing it in the yml file is the only option for me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no easy solution to your problem.

1. You probably know that you can achieve a smiliar behavior using [artifacts: expire_in](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsexpire_in).

In projects where I am concerned about space, I set artifact
expiration to 1 hour and simply forget about it. Maybe you can
elaborate on why you need that behaviour.

2. You already mentioned the GitLab API.

Writing gitlab-ci.yml files is often all the access you need. In the
**script:** section of your job you can call the GitLab API using curl (dependent on your base image, e.g. ubuntu). You may be able to
authenticate your request using pipeline variables (CI_JOB_TOKEN,
CI_SERVER_HOST) as such:

```
https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}
```

Here is a snippet of me calling the API in the pipeline to update a file:

```
call-api:
  image: myimage:latest
  stage: api
  script:
    - |
      curl -v --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --data '{"branch": "main", "author_email": "author@example.com", "author_name": "api", \
      "content": "some content", "commit_message": "update file"}' \
      "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/:project_id/repository/files/target%2Erbproto?ref=main"
```

If these variables do not provide the access you need, you could [define your own variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#define-a-cicd-variable-in-the-ui) for your gitlab project (on a project or group level) that expose an access token with sufficient rights for authentification. If you do it in the UI, you will not have to have a clear-text token in you gitlab-ci.yml, which is worst practice of course.

You then call this request to [delete artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#delete-job-artifacts) in the script section of your pipeline.

I hope this helps. I am sorry that I cannot provide a more straightforward answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and nice answer! I will go with option one first as it seems more reliable and investigate on the second one.